# Notice: Array to string conversion in CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom()

Tags: civicontribute

When I access the live link to one of our contribution pages, the following notice appears. What do I need to do to address it?

Notice: Array to string conversion in CRM_Contribute_Form_ContributionBase->buildCustom() (line 714 of /..../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php)

Comment: what version of civi?

Comment: The version I am using is 4.6.9.